# Split string with bullet points only. Below there is 7 bullet and that is only sentence. 1 bullet is one sentences

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, ruby-on-rails-4

```
xlsx = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(file)
bookname = xlsx.column(1)

tn = xlsx.column(4)
tn_data = tn[1]
p_tn_data = tn_data.split(/\R+/)
puts p_tn_data.to_s
puts p_tn_data.length // it is counting all line as 13, but total sentences is 7 only
```

## Original data:

> ["The apostle John wrote this to Christians.", "• That which was from the beginning - The phrase “That which was from the beginning”", "refers to Jesus, who existed before everything was made. You could translate this as “We", "are writing to you about the one who existed before the creation of all things.”", "• the beginning - “the beginning of all things” or “the creation of the world”", "• we - In verses 1 and 2, the word “we” refers to John and those who knew Jesus when he", "was on this earth, but it does not include the people John was writing to. (See: Exclusive)", "• which we have seen with our eyes, which we have contemplated - “We ourselves have", "seen him.”", "• the eternal life - This phrase also refers to Jesus, who causes us to live forever. It can be", "translated as “that he causes us to live forever.”", "• which was with the Father - “He was with God the Father”", "• and was manifested to us - “but he came to live among us” (UDB)"]

## Getting output:

> The apostle John wrote this to Christians.
>   • That which was from the beginning - The phrase “That which was from the beginning”
>   refers to Jesus, who existed before everything was made. You could translate this as “We
>   are writing to you about the one who existed before the creation of all things.”
>   • the beginning - “the beginning of all things” or “the creation of the world”
>   • we - In verses 1 and 2, the word “we” refers to John and those who knew Jesus when he
>   was on this earth, but it does not include the people John was writing to. (See: Exclusive)
>   • which we have seen with our eyes, which we have contemplated - “We ourselves have
>   seen him.”
>   • the eternal life - This phrase also refers to Jesus, who causes us to live forever. It can be
>   translated as “that he causes us to live forever.”
>   • which was with the Father - “He was with God the Father”
>   • and was manifested to us - “but he came to live among us” (UDB)
>
> > Let me know if need anythings else

### Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get what you need like this:

```
p_tn_data.join('').split('•')
```

First we join the initial data array which will give us a flat string, then we split on every •. This will return 8 Sentences. The first without bullet point and the 7 starting with bullet points.

If you want to keep the actual bullet points you could use a positive lookbehind regular expression like this:

```
p_tn_data.join('').split(/(?=•)/)
```